# How to create Nested JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create a JSON structure like this:

```
TableComponent {
            "Value": {
                    "abc": 
                    "text": "password"
                    },
            "Name": "id",
            "Hidden": "0",
            "ReadOnly": "0",
            "Type": "STRING",
            },
}
```

Though I'm at the initial stage of it. But I want to achieve the JSON mentioned above.

```
var TableComponent = {
    elements: [],
    Components: []
};

var property = {
    prop:[]
};

TableComponent.elements.push(
{
    "id": a.id,
    "abs_x": a.abs_x,
    "abs_y": a.abs_y, 
});
```

I want this "property" inside of "elements" or any other structure suggestion is most welcomed as I'm new to it.

Comment: you can use `JSON.stringify(TableComponent)`.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the two code examples you provided relate to each other. What is "elements"? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to "achieve" the JSON mentioned in the first code example its already there?